# How to use C# regular expressions to emulate forum tags

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex, string

I am building a forum and I want to be able to use simple square bracket tags to allow users to format text. I am currently accomplishing this by parsing the string and looking for the tags. It's very tedious, especially when I run into a tag like this [url=http://www.something.com]Some text[/url]. Having to parse the attribute, and the value, and make sure it has proper opening and closing tags is kind of a pain and seems silly. I know how powerful regular expressions are but I'm not good at them and they frustrate me to no end.

Any of you regex gurus willing to help me out? I think an example would get me started. Just a regex for finding tags like [b]bolded text[/b] and tags with attributes like the link one I listed above would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Links to laymen's terms tutorials for regex are also helpful.

Comment: This is a pretty good site that's been around for a while.  It covers most implementations and has decent writing: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: As Jim Mischel advised, you should take a look at Markdown: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. The "=something.com" is optional and accommodates single or double quotes and it also makes sure that the closing tag matches the opening tag.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = @"My link: [url='http://www.something.com'][b]Some text[/b][/url] is awesome. Jazz hands activate!!";
        string result = Parse(input);
    }

//Result: My link: <a href="http://www.something.com"><b>Some text</b></a> is awesome. Jazz hands activate!!


    private static string Parse(string input)
    {
        string regex = @"\[([^=]+)[=\x22']*(\S*?)['\x22]*\](.+?)\[/(\1)\]";
        MatchCollection matches = new Regex(regex).Matches(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            var tag = matches[i].Groups[1].Value;
            var optionalValue = matches[i].Groups[2].Value;
            var content = matches[i].Groups[3].Value;

            if (Regex.IsMatch(content, regex)) 
            {
                content = Parse(content);
            }

            content = HandleTags(content, optionalValue, tag);

            input = input.Replace(matches[i].Groups[0].Value, content);
        }

        return input;
    }

    private static string HandleTags(string content, string optionalValue, string tag)
    {
        switch (tag.ToLower())
        {
            case "url":
                return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", optionalValue, content);
            case "b":
                return string.Format("<b>{0}</b>", content);
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

### UPDATE

Now i'm just having fun with this. I cleaned it up a bit and replaced the " with \x22 so the entire string can easily be escaped per @Brad Christie's suggestion. Also this regex won't break if there are "[" or "]" characters in the content. Also it handles tags recursively

Comment: @used2could: Using `@` prefix for a literal string would cleanup that Regex tremendously, FYI.

Comment: yeah but there is a " in the pattern and then i'd have to still break it up

Comment: @used2could: Lesser of two evils: repeated ` \\ ` or a single `""`. I'd chose the latter, personally. ;-)

Comment: My preference is the the first unless there weren't any double quotes, then hands down i'd choose @"...".

Comment: @Brad Christie: I did not know that you can just do "" (two) to escape  double quotes when the string is prefixed with @. I thought you had to break the string up like @"some text / string " + "test \" quote" + @".." Thanks!

Comment: @used2could: Glad to pass on part of the 0.01% of knowledge I bestow. ;p

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying that you *can't* do this with regular expressions, but I think you're going to find it very, very difficult.  You'll have to decide what to do with things like `[b]this is [bold text[/b]`, and other cases where the user has `[` or `]` characters. And will you allow nesting? (i.e. `[b]this is bold, [i]italic[/i] text[/b]`).

I would suggest that you look into using something like [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).