# I need help modifying a C# regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, tags, forum

I am using a regex to detect forum tags within posts, such as "[quote]text[/quote]" and then replace them with HTML formatting. I posted a question [Forum tags. What is the best way to implement them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109071/forum-tags-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-them) about a problem with nested tags.

I have an idea, but I need someone's help to help me expand on it (because I suck at regex).

I need this regex modified

`string regex = @"\[([^=]+)[=\x22']*(\S*?)['\x22]*\](.+?)\[/(\1)\]";`

Right now this matches an opening and closing tag, with match groups for the tag name, the tag content, and an optional value like the value after the equals in this forum tag `[url=www.google.com]click me[/url]`.

What I need is for the expression to match the opening tag OR the closing tag and have a match group containing the tag name (including the '/' for the closing tag). I then want to iterate through them sort of like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> tagCollection = new Dictionary<string, int>();
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"expression I'm asking for here",
match =>
{
    string tag = match.Groups[0].Value;
    bool isOpeningTag = tag.StartsWith("/");
    tag = isOpeningTag ? tag : tag.Replace("/","");
    int tagCount = 0;
    if (tagCollection.ContainsKey(tag) && isOpeningTag)
    {
        tagCount = tagCollection[tag];
        tagCollection[tag] = tagCount + 1;
    }
    else if (tagCollection.ContainsKey(tag) && !isOpeningTag)
    {
        tagCount = tagCollection[tag];
        tagCollection[tag] = tagCount - 1;
    }
    else if (!tagCollection.ContainsKey(tag) && isOpeningTag)
        tagCollection.Add(tag, tagCount);

    string newTag = match.Value.Replace(tag, tag + tagCount.ToString());
    return newTag;
});
```

So now, each tag is appended with a number and I could use the original regex to perform the tag functions and properly handle nested tags as separate tags. So really, all I need from you guys is the regex I listed to be modified in the manner I specified.

**Feel free to offer other suggestions as well but I would ask that actual answers focus on the regex modification and not whether or not this is the best way to go about the problem.**

Thanks!

Comment: not a solution, but go grab a copy of RegEx Design from http://www.radsoftware.com.au/   It's a fantastic way to experiment with regex's. I always add it to the external tools list in VS.

Comment: I will be sure to check that out :)

Comment: I like the one here better: Ultrapico http://www.ultrapico.com/

Comment: @Steve Expresso is awesome. I just used it to play with the regex until I got what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\[([^=]+)[=\x22']*(\S*?)['\x22]*\]|\[/(\1)\]`

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, It is a bbcode parser I wrote a while back to basically do exactly what you are doing.

https://github.com/Mike343/Netcoders/tree/master/Coders.Services/Formatters

https://github.com/Mike343/Netcoders/blob/master/Coders.Services/Formatters/BBCodeFormatter.cs

Comment: This is pretty neat. I will likely use it in the future. However I left out some complexity of the project for the sake of simplicity in the question. I really would just like to have the regex I posted modified in the manner I specified. I do appreciate this though. +1

Comment: I know, but I am doing much more complex operations than just swapping out the bbcode for HTML. As I have stated, it is not important. The simple fact is that I would like the regex modified. This is the nature of the question as noted by the line in bold. Like I said, I do appreciate it :)