# How does wikimedia transform its model syntax?

Tags: c#, regex, syntax, wikipedia

I would like to know how does Wikimedia transform its model syntax `({{model|options}})` into html code.
I have a regex for a simple model `({{.*?}})` but it fails for a nested model (ex: `{{model|options containing a {{submodel|options}}...}}`)

Comment: [It's not a good idea to try to parse XML with regexes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) No doubt it uses a real parser.

Comment: When you ask for `regex` helps here, you should always specify the language you are using. The `regex`es of Javascript are less powerful that the ones of C# that (at least for Unicode) are less powerful that the ones of Perl

Comment: I'm using regexes in combination with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember,

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

That said, you can read: [Forum tags. What is the best way to implement them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109071/forum-tags-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-them/5110663#5110663) I made an example of nested tags, both with "pure" Regex and with a "more stable" C# parser that uses a little of Regexes but keeps the stack out of the Regex hands.

You can do it with `balancing groups`. They aren't part of "base" Regex (and some persons don't consider them to be true regexes),

But I wouldn't program something as big as Wiki with something like a regex. The problem of regexes is that it's quite difficult to program them so that they don't backtrack (there is an option to do it, but it's difficult to build a regex that doesn't need backtracking or that need only limited amout of backtracking), and when they begin to backtrack it's the end: they could stall for minutes searching for the right combination of captures.

Comment: So, how do you think that they transform their models to html code ?

Comment: @Sébastien By writing a big chunk of code? :-) It's not by fairies. They could have done something like in my first example and then rebuilt the text with HTML codes (it's quite simple from there). But if you need a parser, I'm quite sure someone has already done it. For example try googling for `Creole C#` (on codeplex http://creoleparser.codeplex.com/)

Comment: HAHA :D - You know how the smart mediawiki developers parse their unspecified markup? - yes regexes...